# Probability mass function find $P(X\leq Y)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> \begin{array}{r|c|c|c}
> y\backslash x&0&1&2\\\hline
> 0&\dfrac{1}{9}&\dfrac29&\dfrac19\\\hline
> 1&\dfrac29&\dfrac29&0\\\hline
> 2&\dfrac19&0&0
> \end{array}
>
> 1. Find $P(X\leq Y)$
> 2. Find $P(X\leq 1|Y=1)$

I can solve this given a function but with a matrix it is confusing me. How do I start?

Comment: I'm assuming that by matrix, you mean joint distribution table, correct?

Comment: @probablyme Please be more careful when you edit, even with good intentions and for a good overall result.

Comment: Wow, that was bad. Thanks @Did . I will be more careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I start?

We have that,
$$P(X\leq Y) = \sum_{j =0}^2P(X\leq Y, Y = j) = \sum_{j = 0}^2P(X\leq j,Y = j)=\sum_{j=0}^2\sum_{i=0}^jP(X=i,Y = j).$$

In other words, one should sum the weights of the places $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,2)$, $(1,2)$ and $(2,2)$.

Comment: Of course! I guess I was just on "auto-pilot". This is much better. Thanks @Did.

Comment: oh wow it is the summing of all the values of where X is less than Y its so obvious working backwards even tho thats what the question asked

Comment: Are you being sarcastic or do you understand what to do now?

Comment: no your answer was perfect i understand what to do is it normal if my covariance(E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)) is negative i got a negative value for this 2/9 - 4/9 = -2/9

Comment: also for the second question is it the sum of the weights at (0,1) (1,1) divided by the sum at Y=1

Comment: It is possible for covariance to be negative. Notice that the two random variables are not independent.  For the second part, that is fine.